# Отрисовать шаровидную спираль , сейчас она получается в виде овала

Tags: javascript

```
  private drawSpiralMarker(startPoint: number[], objectIds: number[]): void {
    let i = 0;
    const qs = objectIds.length - 1;
    const x0 = startPoint[0];
    const y0 = startPoint[1];
    let phi;
    let x;
    let y;

    const spi = {
      r: 0.0001,
      dr: 0.0001,
      ds: 0.0001,
      phi: 0
    };
    setTimeout(() => {
      while (i <= qs) {
        phi = Math.atan2(spi.ds, spi.r);

        spi.phi += phi;
        spi.r += (spi.dr * phi) / (2 * Math.PI);

        x = x0 + spi.r * Math.cos(spi.phi);
        y = y0 + spi.r * Math.sin(spi.phi);

        this.addMarker([x, y], objectIds[i]);
        i += 1;
      }
      this._notLoadingData = false;
    }, 500);
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно все-таки круглую? Шар - это объемная фигура, а у вас тут очевидно плоскость.

Comment: да, круглую , опечатался

Comment: при том что здесь http://jsfiddle.net/hvopgx03/ , данный алгоритм отрабатывает корректно